# spring batch job scheduling best practice

Tags: spring-batch, scheduling, autosys

We have bunch of spring batch jobs and we need to invoke them in specific order. Is there any best practice we should follow? I was thinking of using autosys or cron scheduler based on status of each job and decide whether to invoke next one or not but open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The approach sounds right, though it's harder to build something like this in cron. A scheduler tool like autosys or control-m provide the orchestration feature usually out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I have used CRON to schedule the spring batch jobs . I nearly had to schedule around 3 main jobs and 6 jobs in all of them.

I had a same scenario where the next job is dependent on the first.

In that case you can use spring batch tables to check if the previous job is Completed or not using spring batch tables.

You will find the batch tables details here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html

The tables are -

BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
BATCH_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION

and it will be easy from CRON to schedule the jobs for you .But some how managing jobs in CRON is quite a pain.

TO use a scheduler tool you need to configure it and it will consume a good time. But once the scheduler tool is up , then it is easy to schedule and manage jobs.

In most of the cases - scheduling is one time activity. So i guess it is better not to waist time for scheduler tool , go for CRON instead.